# LAPACK, dgeev_ gives wrong Eigen Vectors for a Stochastic Matrix

Tags: c, lapack

I have the following code for calculating the Eigen Vectors (left and right) of a Stochastic matrix in C (with gcc compiler):

```html
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>



int main()
{
    double A[6][6] = {{0.2,.200000,0.2000000,0.000000,0.200000,0.200000},
{0.200000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.800000},
{0.200000,0.000000,0.000000,0.800000,0.000000,0.000000},
{0.200000,0.000000,0.400000,0.000000,0.400000,0.000000},
{0.200000,0.000000,0.000000,0.800000,0.000000,0.000000},
{0.200000,0.800000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000}};
    
    
    int n=6;
    char Lchar='V';
    char Rchar='V';
    double *eigReal=(double *)malloc(n*sizeof(double *));
    double *eigImag=(double *)malloc(n*sizeof(double *));
    double vl[6][6], vr[6][6];
    int one=1, two=6;
    int lwork=6*n;
    double *work=(double *)malloc(lwork*sizeof(double *));
    int info;
    
    dgeev_(&Lchar,&Rchar,&n,A,&n,eigReal,eigImag,
           vl,&two,vr,&two,
           work,&lwork,&info);
           
           
    for(int i=0; i<6; i++)
    {
        printf("\n");
        for(int j=0; j<6; j++)
        printf("%f ", vr[i][j]); 
    }

    for(int i=0; i<6; i++)
    {
        printf("\n");
        for(int j=0; j<6; j++)
        printf("%f ", vr[i][j]); 
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Then I print `vr` and `vl` to get the following matrices (none of which seems to be correct)
(the ordering of the rows and columns might be wrong i.e it might be the eigen vectors are actually transpose).

```html
0.476331 0.476331 0.264628 0.423405 0.264628 0.476331 
0.852803 -0.213201 0.000000 -0.426401 -0.000000 -0.213201 
0.000000 0.000000 -0.408248 0.816497 -0.408248 0.000000 
0.000000 -0.534522 0.267261 0.534522 0.267261 -0.534522 
0.000000 -0.706706 -0.013739 0.027477 -0.013739 0.706706 
0.550263 -0.137566 0.540215 -0.275132 -0.540215 -0.137566



0.408248 0.408248 0.408248 0.408248 0.408248 0.408248 
0.686304 -0.171576 -0.608494 -0.171576 0.265343 -0.171576 
0.243660 -0.051773 -0.578693 0.517778 -0.578693 -0.009142 
0.000000 -0.447214 0.447214 0.447214 0.447214 -0.447214 
0.000000 -0.707107 -0.000000 -0.000000 -0.000000 0.707107 
0.000000 0.000000 0.707107 0.000000 -0.707107 0.000000
```

So where is the mistake in my code?

Comment: At a quick glance I would suggest looking into how `A[6][6]` is stored in memory and what LAPACK expects. I.e. LAPACK typically work with column major storage as oposed to C/C++ where it is typically row major (though it's simple enough to change how you store the matrix). It might be you are computing the eigenvalues of A^T, which would explain why your eigenvectors are transposed. Disclaimer: I didn't check exactly what you did, just a thought.

Comment: @Qubit i think left and right Eigen vectors take into account that. Both are either right or left Eigen vectors of A aor A^T. Also as a stochastic matrix I expect one column or one row to sum up to 1 which is not happening for any rows or columns.

Comment: LAPACK will always return normalised eigenvectors, so the sum of squares will be 1.

Comment: @Qubit seems like you are correct. Let me investigate a little more. Thnaks.

Comment: @Qubit hello! My preliminary investigation suggests you are correct, although I am not sure exactly how correct it is due to memory causing problems in arrays. So if you want you can write an answer and I'll upvote and accept